# how to overlap sections in html body while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a design in html which has some sections and while scrolling one section falls on top of the previous section like a stack. How to implement it using css, javascript, jquery?
An example of such design is: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/os/?icn=tabz

Comment: Those "sections" are just part of a large page, and they scroll underneath of the fixed header. Nothing too fancy there. Also, you should show use what you've tried (basic HTML layout, a bit of CSS, etc)

Comment: In the example you give the sections are not on top of each other.. they're under each other in the pages normal flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest trick is to use `position:fixed;` to that content.

Here is an [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p76Xv/).

Full blog post is [here](http://www.pixelbind.com/make-a-div-stick-when-you-scroll/).